# TYPO3 does not resolve url correctly

Tags: typo3

I'm pretty new to TYPO3 and currently stuck with the following issue:

I copied the templates from another webpage that is currently in business. 
When I'm on the startpage of my homepage (www.domain.com) and click on one of the links it contains I always get an error 404. The link that is generated looks like this.

`http://www.domain.com/testpage.440.0.html`

So I guess something like RealUrl was in use on the webpage that I copied from? Do I understand this right? I don't see that RealUrl is installed though.

However If i manually change this link to

`http://www.domain.com/?id=440.0.html`

the site is being created.

How does Typo3 know to generate a page when it receives the first version of these two links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does not really look like a standard out-of-the-box REAL URL url. That would rather have been /testpage-404.html . So maybe the problem is somewhere else, could be:

- simulate static (check if that extension is running). A common mistake is to run real url an simulate static at the same time. If you do not need speaking urls for the moment, just uninstall simulate static.
- make sure you add a domain to your shortcut. Use the the list modul and select the root shortcut. Then click create new record, select domain. and enter your domain there. Flush all the caches and try again.

If you'd post your TS Code (of the root shortcut page) here, I could probably tell what's going wrong.

- real url configuration typically use .htaccess files.. maybe that file still contains information from the original destination.
- check if the root ts contains some baseUrl statement

Which version of TYPO3 are you using?

HTH, but feel free to post more infos.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You pointed to the right thing. SimulateStaticDocuments was enabled. For some reason the redirection didn't work correctly. After replacing the .htaccess file with the default one from the Typo3 Dummy package it worked.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are trying to set up Realurl, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If your typoscript template is expecting to find realurl and its not installed as a plugin, that could be the cause. You'll need to either install it, or find the settings in the TS template and remove them.
Try the template object browser to look for it  (use the template tool, click to the site root, then use the drop down menu in the r/h pane to choose the Template Obect Browser.)

> How does Typo3 know to generate a page when 
>   it receives the first version of these two links?

Any page request that it doesn't understand will give a 404 error.